# dynamic execute a function by a string like 'module.function'

Tags: python, dynamic

if I have a string like 'module.function', How can I execute function just by one step?
like`somefunction('os.error','args')`

Comment: define mapping as mentioned on above linked answer or if the function is global globals()[func_name](params,..) where func_name is string.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I do not think that solution is elegant.

Comment: Beware of what you may think is "elegant" in Python, especially if you are coming from other languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dynamically get the modules using [`sys.modules`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.modules) and then you can use [`getattr`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) to get the attributes from the module, like this

```
import sys
func = "os.error"
module, function = func.split(".", 1)
getattr(sys.modules[module], function)()
```

`sys.modules` can give only the modules which are already loaded. So, if you want to load a module dynamically you can use [`__import__`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__) function like this

For example,

```
module, function = "math.factorial".split(".", 1)
print getattr(__import__(module), function)(5)
```

**Output**

```
120
```

Comment: sys.module can only work fine for python standard library, not for user-define module

Comment: @whatout I was already editing my answer :) Please check the update :)

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is

```
from module import function
```

and you'll be able to call

```
function(x, y, z)
```

in your code.

Comment: I think question is about using string name to call function.

Comment: hmm, could be. It's not very clear....